# How can you deploy your substrate-node-template in AWS?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I want to deploy my substrate-node-template to a server in AWS.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I setup a node on an EC2 running Amazon Linux. It was exactly the same approach as needed to setup a node in any linux environment. The only thing different is that you'll need to modify the security groups to expose the proper ports to call RPC endpoints, connect to other nodes, etc.

i.e. if you're running a node with a command like:

```
./target/release/node-template --tmp --dev --alice --port 30333
--ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933 --rpc-cors all --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-methods=unsafe --validator
```

Then you want to expose ports 9944 and 9933 through your security group.

Comment: Thanks so much Tony.  Exactly what I did but had to use NGINX/Proxy to be able to expose the websocket.   But all is well and done.  Thanks so much again