# How to launch substrate chain on server?

Tags: parachain, rococo

Currently i am running my Parachain on rococo-local and it is working as expected.
Now i need to host my parachain on server so that my app can use it.
Is there any guide/process how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this resources:

- This Youtube tutorial: [Deploy Your First Parachain, Tutorial by Adrian Brink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDqkzvA4C0E).
- This [StackExchange previous answer about how to deploy in AWS](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3103/2762).
- This discussion in the polkadot Forum about [Collator node minimal performance requirement](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/determine-collator-node-minimal-performance-requirement/613)
- And for extra detailed information the [The Polkadot Parachain Host Implementers' Guide](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/index.html)